# Como posso capturar um registro de um BD para um combobox e depois de selecionado filtrar com um botao?

Tags: c#

Tenho um chart, um datagrid , dois maskedbox com datas , um botao filtrar e um combobox.
Ja consigo filtrar meus registros no BD e exibir no datagrid e no chart, só que ainda nao consigo filtrar as vendas de cada vendedor, somente todas as vendas. 
Como eu poderia filtrar as vendas de cada vendedor?Gostaria de selecionar o vendedor pelo combobox e que filtrar as vendas do mesmo.

Comment: Porque nao me ajuda meu amigo? Só fica colocando obstaculos.

Comment: Deve ser tão simples mas eu nao sei. Eu preciso , é para meu trabalho, e ninguem me ajuda.

Comment: Não estou colocando obstáculos, amigo. Apenas ia explicar que se já fizeste uma pergunta com essa mesma dúvida, não precisa abrir outra. Se acha que a pergunta anterior não recebeu atenção suficiente, pode editá-la, adicionar mais informações para que os usuários possam te ajudar. Pode ter certeza que se soubesse eu te ajudaria sim. Boa sorte com seu problema!

Comment: Obrigado , vou passar a editar as perguntas a partir de agora e esperar alguem me ajudar.   :)